# The most effective way to split by post type in custom query?

Tags: wp-query

What would be the best way to split custom WP_Query results into different post types?

I'm using multiple queries, but is it the most effective solution in performance terms?

```
$results = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'post_type_1'));
$results2 = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'post_type_2'));

if have posts 
   ...loop $results

if have posts 
   ...loop $results2
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to split the query or do multiple queries. Just use the parameter `orderby` with value `post_type` to sort separated by post types. You can use a second value for additional sorting, e.g. by `date`. See [Codex: Class Reference | WP_Query | Order & Orderby Parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters)  for more information.

Comment: post_type is not an option

Comment: @inarilo It is – `type` or `post_type` van both be used.

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing one query to the database for all results, then use [`get_post_type()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_type/) to break up the results into separate loops for each post type. Depending on the content you're working with it could improve performance if the PHP operations become faster than using two database queries, you'll have to test that for yourself though.

```
<?php
$all_results = new WP_Query([
    'post_type' => ['post_type_1', 'post_type_2'] 
]);

// initiate counter variables
$count_post_type_1s = 0;
$count_post_type_2s = 0;

while ( $all_results->have_posts() ) : $all_results->the_post();
    if( get_post_type($post) == 'post_type_1' ) {
        // increment counter variable for post type 1 being found
        $count_post_type_1s++;
        // post_type_1 output
        the_title();
    }
endwhile;
// check if counter variable is still 0, if it is no post type 1's were found
if( $count_post_type_1s == 0 ) {
    echo "No post type 1's have been found";
}

 // Rewind posts to use same query again
$all_results->rewind_posts();

// do some stuff in between loops

while ( $all_results->have_posts() ) : $all_results->the_post();
    // increment counter variable for post type 2 being found
    $count_post_type_2s++;
    if( get_post_type($post) == 'post_type_2' ) {
        // post_type_2 output
        the_title();
    }
endwhile;
// check if counter variable is still 0, if it is no post type 2's were found
if( $count_post_type_2s == 0 ) {
    echo "No post type 2's have been found";
}
```

Comment: Do you need to rewind posts somehow or it works as is?

Comment: Ben, thanks for your suggestion. While it works it seems I need to separate by type (e.g. for search), like post_type_1 ... posts, post_type_2 ... post and with one query I can’t determine if certain post type has posts or no.

Comment: Not quite sure I follow you, but I updated my answer with some more PHP that echo's a message if there's no posts in each loop. Hopefully that's kind of what you meant?